# Continuous Integration on hardware-centric firmware?

Tags: continuous-integration, embedded, gitlab-ci

How can CI be applied on occasions where implementation requires usage of a firmware's API (hardware-centric i.e. cameras, sensors etc.), or even in the most convenient case, just data obtained from hardware(*) and thus testing online - at least on my understanding - is considered to be impractical?

(*)emulation of data for testing purposes may be considered as a conventional alternative solution (i.e. using pseudo data that emulate data obtained from sensor)..

Are there any common practices for integrating CI on production stages of such hardware-dependent/embedded systems?

Comment: it is unclear to me what you intend to achieve - do you want to just run QA on your embedded application? Or do you for some reason require hardware-based data in order to make decisions in your CI pipeline?

Comment: We develop code that makes use of various hardware devices. For instance code that configures a camera and gets data that are provided to another device and so forth. So using C++ we are able to compile new commits using gitlab-ci but how could we provide CI testing since the software needs the device to be detected? Are there potentially any common practices for such occasions ?

Comment: Have you tried mocking the hardware interfaces or considered using a test harness where the test harness controller would serve as a gitlab-runner, execute a test script and fail or succeed the pipeline according to its results?

Comment: @Sty Would mocking allow "anyone" to configure a device during testing (i.e. set some operational parameters such as the fps of a camera or the sampling rate of a sensor) while also obtain data from it? Also, as for the latter suggestion since it is unclear to me, could you please explain further on how does this work?

Comment: as said, what works and how strongly depends on your setup. E.g. in your case - how important is it to involve a real camera? Can you instead write some application that responds to your detection or configuration code in the way a real camera (approximately) would? If you can do that, you don't need an actual camera, but just your mock application to simulate one. The same application could also respond to data queries with pre-recorded data (which also makes unit testing easier because you have some data about which you know what to expect).

Comment: If you for some reason need to test the camera itself as well, or your application makes use of syscalls that cannot easily be circumvented by mock code, you may want to look into a specialised test harness, i.e. an as-accurate-as-necessary representation of your hardware setup, but with programmatically controllable components and an according test harness controller device that runs said programmatic control of components in test scenarios. In your case that could be a computer that interfaces with your embedded system to simulate a camera or produce a video feed for a camera to pick up

Comment: Clear enough for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Most anything you can do on your local computer, you can reasonably do in a CI process. When it comes to hardware, some techniques to test this on cloud-provider CI systems might be to use software emulators. If a software simulator is not available, you might simply mock out those interfaces in your tests.

If testing on the actual hardware is important, you can attach your hardware to your CI job runner. For example, at my company we have proprietary hardware for our product. We have a 'test rack' which has several of these devices connected to our self-hosted [GitLab CI runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/). This gives developers who write the firmware, OS, and software that runs on the hardware the ability to script and test against the actual hardware.

Some popular hardware (mobile devices) are available 'as a service' in the cloud, too, in "device farms" (usually mobile devices like iPhones) such as [AWS device farm](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/); however based on your description of the devices you're working with, this doesn't sound like it will be available as a service.